# Некоректные ответы, выдаваемые программой

Tags: c++

Помогите, плз. Написал примитивный калькулятор  принимающий от пользователя выражения:+, -, /, *,. Так он несмотря на введенные числа выдает однинаковые ответы для для выражений с одинаковыми мат. операциями. Так например 2+2,  4+8 и тд. будут равны.То же справедливо и для других мат. операций. Программа написана в двух СРР файлах + один заголовочный файл.
Код по ссылке здесь

ЗЫ: насчет предоставления кода, я пытался его поставить в текстовку да только гемороя много:шарп делает текст жирным-большим, содержимое в угловых скобках не отображается и тд.

Comment: Я предлагаю вам выдрать ту часть кода, которая отвечает конкретно за математику и выложить её сюда.

Comment: Код в студию!

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ошибка находится здесь:

```
double x, y;
char sig;
// ...
scanf("%f%c%f", &x, &sig, &y);
```

scanf c "%f" запишет значение типа float, а у вас две переменные типа double. Ваш scanf нужно заменить на

```
std::cin >> x >> sig >> y;
```

или на

```
scanf("%lf%c%lf", &x, &sig, &y);
```

Comment: спасибо ГРАМОТНОМУ товарищу gkuznets'у. Действительно проблема решилась. НО еще вопрос: набираю exit для выхода - включаетя бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Насколько я помню, у вас в цикле сравнивается значение переменной input c "exit", при этом сама переменная input никогда не обновляется.

Comment: Именно так